# php INSERT data to sql in for loop

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a mysql insert statement in a for-loop. `I'm looking for to insert multiple records at a time.`

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$label =htmlspecialchars( $_POST["label"]);
$splitLabel = explode(" ", $label);//split the label to a array
}
//.....insert another data, getting the $last_id here

$sql = $result = "";
for ($i =0; $i< count($splitLabel); $i++){
    if ($i < count($splitLabel)){
        $sql .= "INSERT INTO label (item_id, label)
        VALUES ('".$last_id."', '".$splitLabel[$i]."');";
    }else{
        $sql .= "INSERT INTO label (item_id, label)
        VALUES ('".$last_id."', '".$splitLabel[$i]."')";
    }
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

i got a error about

```
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO label (item_id, label)
    VALUES ('13', 'tin');INSERT INTO label (' at line 2
```

the label tabel:

```
Field      Type           null
item_id    int(11)         NO
label      varchar(50)     NO
```

i cannot find the mistake, please help me to find it..

Comment: The label table has no 'PRIMARY KEY'

Comment: mysqli_query() executes _one_ statement. But e.g. `INSERT ... ; INSERT ...;` are two statements. see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php  | But exactly why do you need multiple statements, esp. when they all hit the same table?

Comment: Use [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) to execute multiple query

Comment: In your case, only if condition will execute . Why did you wrote if and else??

Comment: i want to Insert Multiple Records Into MySQL.... in the for loop

Comment: Have a look this link once http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple query execution you can use [mysqli_multi_query()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp)

For multi insertion to a table with single query is like this [multi insert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):-

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

So you can try like

```
$sqlInsert   = '';
$countOfData = count($splitLabel);
for ($i = 0; $i < $countOfData; $i++){
    $sqlInsert .= "('{$last_id}', '{$splitLabel[$i]}'),";
}
$sqlInsert = rtrim($sqlInsert, ',');//remove the extra comma
if ($sqlInsert) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO label (item_id, label) VALUES {$sqlInsert} ;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

mysqli_query() excutes exactly one statement, but you're sending multiple statements. You *could* use [mysqli_multi_query()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php), but ....

better use a [prepared statement + parameters](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for that.
Something like e.g

```
if ( isset($_POST["label"]) ) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO label (item_id, label) VALUES (?,?)')
    if ( !$stmt ) {
        someErrorHandler( $conn->error );
    }
    else if ( !$stmt->bind_param('ss', $last_id, $label) ) {
        someErrorHandler( $stmt->error );
    }
    else {
        // I have no idea where this $last_id comes from ....
        foreach( explode(' ', $_POST["label"]) as $label ) {
            if ( !$stmt->execute() ) {
              someErrorHandler( $stmt->error );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) for multiple queries.

```
$sql = "";
$result = "";

for ($i =0; $i< count($splitLabel); $i++){
    if ($i < count($splitLabel)){
        $sql .= " INSERT INTO label (item_id, label)
        VALUES ('".$last_id."', '".$splitLabel[$i]."');";
    }else{
        $sql .= " INSERT INTO label (item_id, label)
        VALUES ('".$last_id."', '".$splitLabel[$i]."');";
    }
}
$result = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql);
```

You can not use multiple INSERT into single `mysqli_query` for this action, you can use `mysqli_multi_query()` for executing multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$label =htmlspecialchars( $_POST["label"]);
$splitLabel = explode(" ", $label);//split the label to a array
}
//.....insert another data, getting the $last_id here

$sql = $result = "";
for ($i =0; $i< count($splitLabel); $i++){
if ($i < count($splitLabel)){
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO label (item_id, label) VALUES ('$last_id', '$splitLabel[$i]')";
}else{
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO label (item_id, label)
    VALUES ('$last_id', '$splitLabel[$i]')";
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO label (item_id, label)
    VALUES ('".$last_id."', '".$splitLabel[$i]."');";
```

You missed ";"

Comment: Try with ";", then you wil know .

Comment: @kingyau  always finish your statements with ; - it's syntax delimiter, there's no other way... don't forget, you're joining multiple strings with for loop. try to echo your $sql before execution to see what exactly goes into query process. btw, like others suggested, use mysqli_multi_query() to execute this kind queries or consider using PDO->query (witch allows multi-queries) and also you don't need multiple queries when inserting into same table; you can insert thousands of rows into same table with just one INSERT command (see documentation).

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 can you suggest some documentation for this problem?

Comment: @kingyau The best resources for all php/mysql developers are [php.net](http://www.php.net) and [mysql.com](http://www.mysql.com). Your problem could be solved using [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) (most likely). generally, there you can find all you need to learn php and mysql properly.

Answer (score -2):

Try this one.

```
   $sql = $result = "INSERT INTO label (item_id, label) VALUES ";
   for ($i =0; $i< count($splitLabel); $i++){    
        $sql .= "('".$last_id."', '".$splitLabel[$i]."')";
        if ($i < count($splitLabel) - 1){
            sql .= ",";
        }
    }
```

Comment: He want to insert multiple values at time

Comment: he is using mysqli. can you prepare on sample for mysqli multi insert. so you get +ve vote.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11444821)